# tensorflow-gpu on Windows: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

I am trying to install Tensorflow with GPU support on Windows 10 according to the following guide: https://nitishmutha.github.io/tensorflow/2017/01/22/TensorFlow-with-gpu-for-windows.html

However, I got the following error when I import tensorflow in Conda Python 3.5.2:

How I fix this dll-not-found error? 'pip install tensorflow-gpu' did not give any errors.

> File "", line 666, in _load_unlocked
>     File "", line 577, in module_from_spec
>     File "", line 906, in create_module
>     File "", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
>   ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41,
>    in                                                                                                             from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
>     File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in                                                                                                        _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()                                                                  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>    line 20, in swig_import_helper
>       return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
>     File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
>        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
>   ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'
>
> Failed to load the native
>   TensorFlow runtime.
>
> See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems
>   for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
>   above this error message when asking for help.
>
> > > 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tensorflow installation with pip did not give any errors, but I fixed my problem by installing CuDNN V6 instead of CuDNN V5.1. It appears that tensorflow V1.3.0 now uses CuDNN V6.

Answer (score 0):

You have the option of installing Tensorflow with native pip on windows.
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows

You may use the python script ([tensorflow_self_check.py](https://gist.github.com/mrry/ee5dbcfdd045fa48a27d56664411d41c)) to check the problems during the installation.